# ORA-01722: invalid number in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

if i used like this im not get any error

`(ph.x_date >= to_date('01/05/2016') and ph.x_date <= to_date('01/04/2020'))`

but if range is big like this

`(ph.x_date >= to_date('01/05/2002') and ph.x_date <= to_date('01/04/2020'))`

i get invalid number error.
where is my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Never use `to_date()` without explicitly specifying the format you are passing.

Comment: What data type is the column `x_date`?

Comment: Your mistake may not be in the criteria you use but is instead in the results you retrieve. Check if there is a convert issue in your SELECT clause

Comment: x_date type is date

Answer (score 1):

`To_date()` has to be always used when you know the date data would come in a particular format always that you know before hand. Use to_date like this `To_date('date', <dateformat>)` this reads the date in the explicit format that you may want to make it read.

In your case it reads default but what if your order of retrieval changes in your x_date i guess your data in xdate column has some issues. Check data before 2016. Different order like `mm/yy/dd` or etc data different from the to_date format is there

Comment: GUYS, GUYS, GUYS!!! If, as the OP states, the x_date column is of type DATE, then _it has no format_.    DATE data types are oracle's internal, binary format.  The to_date function converts a _string_ into this internal, binary format.  Talk about comparing the format of the column to the format of TO_DATE is nonsense.  I _will_ grant that the to_date should also include the format mask.  However, the format mask describes the format of the string being converted, not some internal format for comparison.

Comment: Read my answer once again your comment doesnt make any sense. Did u see what my last few lines say about OPs data issue

Comment: I probably should have more directed my earlier remark towards this:   "and make sure the date format _you get from the table_ is the same as you specified" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the format of date, e.g. `to_date('01/05/2002','DD/MM/YYYY')` and make sure the date format you get from the table is the same as you specified

Answer (score 0):

I think your data in SELECT list is having an issue

Please check the output of the below command and see whether it returns the output

```
 select *
 from  data ph 
 where ph.x_date >= to_date('01/05/2002') and 
 ph.x_date <=to_date('01/05/2016')  ;
```

Comment: you said data in x_date has some issues but it could be any column in the select list